# How do I programmatically convert an ebook from one format to another?

Tags: scripting, file-format

I've been dealing with ebooks lately, and found it quite hard to quickly find conversion scripts to and from the numerous formats available (EPUB, lrf, html, txt, rtf, markdown, and so on).

I thought it might be nice to have one post here with **one formats pair and one corresponding tool** (eg. `Markdown -> Pdf, markdown2pdf`) per answer. This should give everyone a neat way to rate the various tools based on their experience, and I think that such a list could be handy for many people.

Hope you like the idea!

Comment: Which program to run is not a programming question

Comment: @Kevin: Which lib to use, then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this might work for you: http://manual.calibre-ebook.com/cli/ebook-convert.html

Comment: Alright, although what I had in mind was rather libraries.